# How do I set up a Tensorflow cluster using Google Compute Engine Instances to train a model?

Tags: kubernetes, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-platform

I understand can use docker images, but do I need Kubernetes to create a cluster? There are instructions available for model serving, but what about model training on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kubernetes [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) to run batch compute tasks. But currently (circa v1.6) it's not easy to set up data pipelines in Kubernetes.

You might want to look at [Pachyderm](http://pachyderm.io/), which is a data processing framework built on top of Kubernetes. It adds some nice data packing/versioning tools.